AES Decrypt in Salesforce over 1MB
Has anyone used JS in SF to view encrypted (standard apex encryption) file which is >1MB? I came across this link but unsure if it will work using LWC in Salesforce. Iam looking for similar workaround and reference of github link, if any.
The other options suggested to customer
1.Compress the file to ensure it is >1MB before it lands in SF
2.Let Middleware send the file to document management system and share the link with SF who can use API call to simply view it

Does this answer your question? Workaround for AES decryption limit of 1 MB
